# Resurrect dead linux (debian-based), caused by misplaced

Tags: boot, linux-mint, kernel, grub2

Mainly is to resurrect dead linux, which dead by accident.
The last time I use it, I am opening 3 GUI terminal with some sudo. I am not sure but I just learning to use pushd and popd at that time, my suspicion is that what kills my lovely mint. I am using the GUI(via taskbar) to do the update, not using `apt` on a terminal.

The dead linux is linux mint 18 which upgraded to 20.1.

the kernel version in details, sda6`/`:

```
 memtest86+.bin
 memtest86+.elf
 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
 System.map-5.4.0-72-generic
 System.map-5.8.0-50-generic
 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
 vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
 vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
```

- The [fstab](https://gist.github.com/sukrosono/db90a6142e34677d66b7cf299bf77858)

  > note the error there no longer relevant now
- [blkdid](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sukrosono/d518d7ec058147fa8a1fc6b48326deb3/raw/5d9a87615d403c3e594ebfcac4f38bfcf1edf948/arch.blkid.md)
- [lsblik](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sukrosono/e9b2c8825a361df9924aeb360b7b9b56/raw/d3701b498690b28b48600be2b18d72e995b4fdc2/lsblk.md)
- the correct file(I assume) located nested on sda6 partition, /var/foo/bar/baz. The file is missplaced by accident, including my home folder.

### Current boot sequence

```
set root=hd0,msdos6
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
load_video
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzio
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 3f3fce91-72f7-403f-90d2-aaaadc657cbc
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=3f3fce91-72f7-403f-90d2-aaaadc657cbc rw quiet nosplash debug
initrd /initrd.img
```

When I use set prefix=/subdirectory/foo, the busybox yield normal.mod, foo.mod not found.
but now yield the `init` fail with /opt or /proc directory already exist. I will update these details with the ongoing action in this question.

#### Attempted:

- manually copy the file from live mint(via thumb drive) file to my sda6.
- read the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/admin-guide/init.html)
- using the set prefix=($root)/var/foo/bar/ , but still goes to busy box, with no specific error. Or I can't identify which error should I mention here

I also need an assistant to navigate on `busybox` to provide the necessary log.

The question is how to fix the grub2-boot loader so my dead mint can be resurrected.
If I am separating my problem and my question correctly, I will form the question, How to correct my prefix on boot sequence?
Somehow I am dead sure this is possible, just not know yet how to do it.